# How to create a form and insert form data to database in ExpressionEngine?

Tags: safecracker, forms, mysql, solspace-freeform

I am developing a website in ExpressionEngine and I am a newbie for ExpressionEngine and CodeIgniter.

I want to create a form on page and want to insert it data after submission to my customized table in ExpressionEngine .

I don't want to go deep in ExpressionEngine. I just want a form on page and when user submit the form all fields value insert into my custom table.

Comment: It's probably worth asking why you want to insert data into a new table. EE has the concepts of channels and entries built in, which are basically their own tables, and you can do all this without a single line of PHP.

Comment: If you don't want to "go deep into Expressionengine" and want a custom table with a form inserting data then there is nothing to stop you doing this alongside other EE driven content on the site. Simply create your form and necessary PHP script(s) as required. It's only if you wanted to insert the data into EE's tables that you'd need to consider how EE works.

Comment: @foamcow, can you move your comment to an answer? More appropriate there IMO.

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl done as requested. When I wrote that it was originally a question but I edited it while writing and lost the question part!

Answer (score 5):

This will definitely require a module. I recommend taking a look into the developer documentation to get a feel for this. I wouldn't write any code to do what you want without a plugin or module. It's not too difficult to get started.

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/index.html

You can use Pkg.io to make your life easier. This will create an installable module as a boilerplate automatically for you. So really, it's the least amount of effort to get a module up and running.

http://pkg.io/

Also, take a look at Base Form class, which is my library for making building front-end forms in EE easier. You can use my free add-on Authenticate as an example of how to use it. It has a lot of options already built-in.

https://github.com/objectivehtml/Base-Form

https://github.com/objectivehtml/Authenticate

Answer (score 1):

It's actually possible to leverage some of the underlying framework directly in a template (by enabling PHP input parsing for that particular template obviously). It's obviously depending on what you intend to do. But, for example, I'm using that to display a form that once posted will either show a page with errors or send an e-mail (making use of the EE object and input, form_validation and output library).
If the form is not too complicated, this is probably a good way to make something fast. Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to "go deep into Expressionengine" and want a custom table with a form inserting data then there is nothing to stop you doing this alongside other EE driven content on the site. Simply create your form and necessary PHP script(s) as required. It's only if you wanted to insert the data into EE's tables that you'd need to consider how EE works.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/external-entries and [External SAEF](http://engaging.net/products/external-saef)? Seems pretty straightforward. You can easily insert new entries in a table from an other database.

Answer (score 0):

There are several "EE form add-ons" you may want to consider that do the PHP job for you, and essentially store all the data in their own tables as you stated is something you want to do.  Each has their own advantages/disadvantages, depending on the use case.

The form add-ons I know of are:

- [FreeForm](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freeform)
- [ProForm](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/proform-drag-and-drop-form-builder)
- [Forms](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/forms)

FreeForm has certainly been around the longest, and recently underwent a major overhaul.

Answer (score 0):

To break down the above answers [FreeForm](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freeform) is great if you don't already have a database table created, and [External Entries](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/external-entries) is great if you *do* already have a database table that you need to work with.