# What's the best EE Add-on for multipage / multistep forms?

Tags: forms

I'm hoping to get some feedback from the community on what people's experiences have been with regard to setting up multipage (multistep) forms with these add-ons for a project I'm working on:

- [FreeForm](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freeform)
- [ProForm](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/proform-drag-and-drop-form-builder)
- [Forms](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/forms)

Key functionality I'm looking for is as follows:

- Ability to allow users to go "back" to previous steps
- Ability to ensure users cannot proceed to next step unless required fields are filled in
- Ability to use a Jquery form validation method (with form module as backup)
- Compatibility with [Snaptcha](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/snaptcha)
- Nice to have: show a summary of data submitted in all steps before final submission

*Disclaimer: It's ironic that I'm asking this question, because I just recently gave a recommendation in [this SE thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/3603/how-to-create-a-form-and-insert-form-data-to-database-in-expressionengine/4751#4751) about EE forms.*

Comment: This isn't an answer but here's a stepped form I created on a project last year: http://www.destinationcolorado.com/submit-rfp. It's all on one page and uses jQuery to move through the steps an to handle validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For really complex forms, I use SafeCracker.

It covers most of your requirements.

Users can go "back" to previous steps, as the entry is created as result of step 1, user can return to editing anytime they want.

Snaptcha (and other anti-spam techniques) are supported, of course.

For form validation, I'm using jQuery validation (built-in validation cannot be used, as the actual entry is split between several forms).

The summary can be shown anytime.

To have notification emailed at proper time, the entry can be submitted with 'Pending' or 'closed' status and changing status to 'open' at final step.

Comment: Thanks for this perspective. I really dig the fact that each step would be saved and never lost, even if a user abandons ship at step x.

Answer (score 3):

The guys at Focuslab have you covered with this article: http://focuslabllc.com/blog/form-building-add-ons-in-expressionengine

Lays out the major differences between the different form add-ons.

Comment: That's an awesome write-up. I did some google searching prior to submitting this question but for some reason that never turned up. Good find. Thanks Erwin.

Comment: No prob, I'm a chronic bookmarker :)

Answer (score 0):

Solspace Freeform Pro does multi step forms and although I've never used this aspect of it, it's pretty good.